# how to make query select statement result like this?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

i'm using postgre sql and i want to select data from database like this

```
------------------------------------
total1 | total2 | total3 | province|
------------------------------------
1      |1       |2       |Maluku   |
2      |3       |4       |Aceh     |
4      |7       |2       |Riau     |
------------------------------------
```

but my result from query like this

```
------------------------------------
total1 | total2 | total3 | province|
------------------------------------
1      |1       |2       |Maluku   |
1      |1       |2       |Aceh     |
1      |1       |2       |Riau     |
------------------------------------
```

my query

```
SELECT (SELECT COALESCE(COUNT(id),0) FROM vent) as total1, 
       (SELECT COALESCE(COUNT(id),0) FROM ventWHERE jenis='Vent-I') as total2,
       (SELECT COALESCE(COUNT(id),0) FROM ventWHERE status='Terpakai') as total3, 
        b.provinsi as province 
FROM public."admin_provinsi" as b LEFT JOIN 
     public."rs" as a 
     on a.provno = b.idprov 
GROUP BY b.provinsi, b.idprov 
ORDER BY total1 DESC
```

how to make result of the query like that?

my scheme database
table vent

```
|id|jenis |id_rs|status  |
--------------------------
|1 |vent-i|1    |Terpakai|
|2 |vent-i|2    |Tidak   |
```

table rs

```
|gid|name     |provno|
-----------------
|1  |rs depok | 1    |
|1  |rs depok2| 1    |
```

table admin_provinsi

```
|idprov|nama  |
---------------
|1     |Maluku|
|2     |Aceh  |
|3     |Riau  |
```

Comment: add your schema here.

Comment: oke wait sir ...

Comment: whats the logic you use to obtain desired result. Any formula to determine the values

Comment: @ZmxAtah . . . Your question makes no sense.  How do you get a count of "4" or "7" from the sample data?  How is `total1` NOT the largest count?